# Find the Automorphism group of a Brandt semigroup $B(G,2)$ ,where $G $ is a cyclic group of order 4

Tags: semigroups

> Find the Automorphism group of a Brandt semigroup $B(G,2)$ ,where $G $ is a cyclic group of order 4.

Take $G=\{ e, a ,a^2, a^3\}$

$B(G,2) = \{ (i,a^s , j) : 1 \leq i,j \leq 2  \ \  , 0\leq s  \leq 3 \} \cup \{0\}$ and the binary operation is defind by
$$(i, a^r , j) (k,a^s , l)  = \begin{cases} (i,a^ra^s,l) & \text{if }  \ \ j=k \\
0 &\text{if } otherwise \end{cases}$$

Comment: This is not really research level. The endomorphisms of any Rees matrix semigroup are described in any standard text and yours is particularly easy.

Comment: Basically i am interested to find the Automorphism group of $B(G,n)$, where $G$ is any group. I know that the $B_n $ is isomorphic to $S_n$. I want to gneralize this result.

Comment: The generalization you want can be found in standard semigroup books.  You can conjugate by permutation matrices and apply group automorphisms and combine these two operations.  Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin Steinberg remarked, this special case is not very complicated and does not need my answer. However the automorphism group of $B(S,n)$, where $S$ is a monoid and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, was completely determined in [Gutik](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06085) (see Theorem 2).